# GSON default serializer failed in JUnit

Tags: junit4, powermockito

I am using Gson to serialize an object, it works fine in the execution. But when I am adding JUnit4 testing case using the latest PowerMockito. I am seeing error of

"UnsuppoprtedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: com.mmypackage.MyClass. Forgot to register a type adapter?"

Why is it different in JUnit4/PowerMockito and normal execution?